# Defining a wildcard text index in spring data for mongodb with default language via Annotation

Tags: mongodb, wildcard

I am currently trying to create a wildcard text index for a model in spring data for MongoDB (v.2.3.7, with MongoDB 4.2.8 Community) via annotations.

Currently, I use the `@CompoundIndex` annotation to create this index. This works fine in general, the index is automatically created in MongoDB in the collection. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to set the default_language with this annotation, so the index always gets created with the default language, which is English.

Here is the basic (shortened) definition of the model:

```
@Document(collection = "events")
@CompoundIndexes({
    @CompoundIndex(name = "fulltext", def = "{'$**':'text'},{default_language:'german'}")
})
public class Event {
    public Event() {
    }

    protected String name;
...
}
```

As you can see I simply (nad naively) tried to add the `default_language` property as part of the `def` attribute in the annotation, but it seems to get ignored. According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/index/CompoundIndex.html#def--), the value of the `def` attribute is basically used as the "actual index definition in JSON format" for the create index call in MongoDB, so I thought it might work this way. Well, it does not. Seems the second part of the definition gets simply ignored.

If I create the index directly in mongo shell using the following command, all works fine and I can see the index to be created with the language settings:

```
> db.events.createIndex({'$**':'text'},{default_language: "german"})
```

Does anybody have an idea of how to use annotations to create the wildcard text index with a specific default language?
I am fully aware that I could probably programmatically solve this issue by something like

```
TextIndexDefinitionBuilder text = new TextIndexDefinitionBuilder().onAllFields().withDefaultLanguage("german").build();
```

But using annotations would just be so much more elegant to keep the code base slim.